# Help with simple probability question

Tags: probability

Let $X$ have distribution function

$F_{X}(x)$ = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } a = 1, \\
  \frac{1}{2}z^2, & \text{if 0 ≤ x ≤ 2}, \\
   1, & \text{if } x > 2.
\end{cases}

Let $Y = X^2$.

Find  $P(X + Y ≤\frac{3}{4})$.

All I have done is:

$P(X + Y ≤\frac{3}{4}) = P(X + X^2 ≤\frac{3}{4})$.

What should I do next?

Comment: What are $a$ and $z$ ?.${}{}$

Answer (score 0):

You should find the maximum value of $X$ that has $X+X^2 \le \frac 34$.  Call it $a$.  Then determine $P(X \le a)$

Answer (score 0):

$$X+X^2 \leq \frac34 $$

$$X^2+X-\frac34 \leq 0$$

$$4X^2+4X-3 \leq 0$$

$$(2X+3)(2X-1) \leq 0$$

$$  -\frac32 \leq  X\leq \frac12$$

Hence you should find $P(-\frac32 \leq X \leq \frac12)$

Comment: That makes sense, thank you